# Ember.js - CRUD scenarios - Specifying View from within a Route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing, ember-old-router

I've asked a question previously in which I wanted to [bind a collection residing in the controller to the list scenario view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301798/ember-js-how-to-properly-bind-a-collection-to-a-view-using-ember-router), however, I've added *details* and *edit* templates and views to my structure producing a couple of extra sub-routes:

`root.contacts.details -> /contacts/:contact_id`
`root.contacts.edit -> /contacts/:contact_id/edit`

In my `details` scenarios I first started calling the `connectOutlets` as follows

```
[...]
connectOutlets: function (router, contact) {
    router.get('contactController').set('contact', contact);
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('contacts');
},[...]
```

This would change the route in the browser navigation bar, but it would load the same view, then I changed the `.connectOutlet` to ***contact* instead of *contacts*** to the following

```
[...]
connectOutlets: function (router, contact) {
    router.get('contactController').set('contact', contact);
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('contact');
},[...]
```

Because of this, I had to create a new controller as Ember couldn't find a controller named `contactController`, so I ended up with a `contactController` and a `contactsController` and I think I'm breaking the MVC pattern doing this, as well as creating an extra class to maintain, possible problems with syncronization (when editing a contact I'd have to manually sync with the collection in the `contactsController`). Also when I navigate to `/#/contacts/2/edit` it loads the details view since I'm using the same name in `.connectOutlet('contact')`. So what I'm doing can't be right. I don't want to create controller per scenario. I'm sure this is not how it's done.

I also tried setting the view (in my case `App.EditContactView`) instead of the resource name in the `connectOutlets` but I got an error saying I can pass "*a name or a viewClass but not both*" but I was not passing through `viewClass` and rather as an argument of `connectOutlet`.

I have also tried to set a view or an instance of my view to the route itself and I would either break my JavaScript or in some cases I'd get an error saying that "*App.EditContactView does not have a method CharAt*".

Then again, I got a little lost. I have seen other questions at SO and else where but the ones I've found were either using [`ember-routermanager`](https://github.com/ghempton/ember-routemanager) by Gordon Hempton (which seems good, but I'm interested in using built-in only right now), `Ember.StateManager` or not using state/route at all. Documentation isn't explaining too much about these things yet.

**Question**: What would be the ideal approach to deal with all CRUD scenarios with `Ember.Router`?
I want my `contactsController` to be able to list all, find one, edit one, add one and delete one contact. Right now I have one `contactsController` with `findAll` and one `contactController` with `find`, `edit`, `remove`, `add` because of naming problems.

I am currently not using ember-data so I would be more interested in examples without references to ember-data (I am doing the baby steps without any plug-in for now).

Here's the current version of my router:

**JS**

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    location: 'hash',

    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        // EVENTS
        gotoHome: Ember.Route.transitionTo('home'),
        gotoContacts: Ember.Route.transitionTo('contacts.index'),

        // STATES
        home: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
            }
        }),
        contacts: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/contacts',
            index: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                contactDetails: function (router, context) {
                    var contact = context.context;
                    router.transitionTo('details', contact);
                },
                contactEdit: function (router, context) {
                    var contact = context.context;
                    router.transitionTo('edit', contact);
                },
                connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                    router.get('contactsController').findAll();
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('contacts', router.get('contactsController').content);
                }
            }),
            details: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/:contact_id',
                view: App.ContactView,
                connectOutlets: function (router, contact) {
                    router.get('contactController').set('contact', contact);
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('contact');
                },
                serialize: function (router, contact) {
                    return { "contact_id": contact.get('id') }
                },
                deserialize: function (router, params) {
                    return router.get('contactController').find(params["contact_id"]);
                }
            }),
            edit: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/:contact_id/edit',
                viewClass: App.EditContactView,
                connectOutlets: function (router, contact) {
                    router.get('contactController').set('contact', contact);
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('contact');
                },
                serialize: function (router, contact) {
                    return { "contact_id": contact.get('id') }
                },
                deserialize: function (router, params) {
                    return router.get('contactController').find(params["contact_id"]);
                }
            })
        })
    })
});
App.initialize();
```

**Relevant templates**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact-details">
    {{#if controller.isLoaded}} 
        <img {{bindAttr src="contact.imageUrl" alt="contact.fullName" title="contact.fullName"}} width="210" height="240" /><br />
        <strong>{{contact.fullName}}</strong><br />
        <strong>{{contact.alias}}</strong>
    {{else}}
        <img src="images/l.gif" alt="" /> Loading...
    {{/if}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact-edit">
    <strong>Edit contact</strong><br />
    First Name: <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" {{bindAttr value="contact.firstName"}}<br />
    Lasst Name: <input type="text" id="txtLastName" {{bindAttr value="contact.lastName"}}<br />
    Email: <input type="text" id="txtEmail" {{bindAttr value="contact.email"}}<br />
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact-table-row">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img {{bindAttr src="contact.imageUrl" alt="contact.fullName" title="contact.fullName"}} width="50" height="50" /><br />{{contact.fullName}}
        </td>
        <td>
            Twitter: {{#if contact.twitter}}<a {{bindAttr href="contact.twitter"}} target='_blank'>Follow on Twitter</a>{{else}}-{{/if}}<br />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" {{action contactDetails context="contact"}}>Details</a> | 
            <a href="#" {{action contactEdit context="contact"}}>Edit</a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

**Note**: If there's anything unclear, please ask in the comment section and I can edit this with more details

**Edit**: I've added this project to [GitHub](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router) even tho it's nowhere near what I'd like to expose as a learning sample. The goal is to progress on top of this and create a CRUD template in a near future. Currently using MS Web API, but might add a Rails version soon.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for the link to the Github page.  Has this changed recently?

Comment: Yeah.. I've changed the project name. Here's the [new link](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a few things going on here, I'll try and answer them, but if I miss anything feel free to leave a comment. You seem to be reinventing a lot of stuff Ember already does for you.

Firstly, if you want to pass a view to the `connectOutlet` method you need to pass in a hash as the one and only argument.

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
  viewClass: App.EditContactView,
  controller: router.get('contactsController'),
  context: context
})
```

Secondly, having two contact controllers is not frowned upon, in fact I'd recommend it. A singular `ContactController` that inherits from `ObjectController` and a `ContactsController` that inherits from `ArrayController`, this means you can easily take advantage of the content proxies built in.

Thirdly, if you add `find` and `findAll` class methods to your models you will make life much easier for yourself.

- You won't need to define the serialize/deserialize methods you have defined, by default Ember will look for a model with the name deduced from the route so :contact_id will automatically look for App.Contact.find(:contact_id).
- You will also be able to change your index connectOutlets to: `router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('contacts', App.Contact.findAll())`

One more tip, currently your details and edit routes are almost completely identical. I would create a single route called `company` and then make child details and edit views inside of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll go bit by bit on this, but before I try it out, I'd like to know more about the controllers, how do you go about to sync data? Say you have a create method in the controller which inherits from `ObjectController`, would you manually copy a record that was created by an `ObjectController` instance to the collection in the `ArrayController`? Maybe I'm being too strict, but I don't think I like having multiple controllers for the same resource type, is this the convention in Ember? (I had a different app using StateManager with a single controller for this resource)

Comment: If I call my `edit` route with this code in the `connectOutlet`, it throws the message `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You must supply a name or a view class to connectOutlets, but not both`

Comment: I've changed `viewClassName: App.EditContactView` to `viewClass: App.EditContactView`. I no longer get the previous error message, but my route and view won't load. The url stays the same and the view stays the same, just with no data now.

Comment: Just noticed that the `connectOutlet` I copied from your answser is passing `contactsController` instead of `contactController`. Now after these changes I am able to load my view. Thanks :) I just wish the documentation was more explicit about the controllers, not my favorite approach right now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try actually double-check my code, I'm glad you worked it out. I'm currently doing everything with Ember-Data so I guess I'm kind of used to having a general store of objects abstracted outside of the controllers.

Comment: As for the singular vs plural controllers, I see it as a currentObject vs collection of Objects controllers, obviously you are going to be doing completely different things to the collection (iterating/sorting/filtering) than you are to a single object (creating/editing/deleting). Obviously you can use whatever structure suits you, but I'm this seems to be a pattern I've seen quite a bit in code samples

Comment: Yeah, although it's not what I would ideally do in a regular mvc application (my background is .net btw), I think I might adopt this pattern for controllers as well because after this question I've also started to see more and more of it being applied elsewhere. At the same time, I might go back to single controller since I can define which controller I'll be using throught `connectOutlet` so I could have a `selectedContact` property for this in the `ArrayController`. I'll try it out more later today. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Ember-Data looks amazing and I intend to use it as soon as I feel confident about coding with the built-in functionality. Ember is being a great experience and I think I'll stick to it over Knockout, which was my previous MV* library of choice

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Very interesting post. I think you should have a look directly to the source of controller, router, route. The documentation about this is not up to date, as the code is moving very often. Moreover, I think the examples are too small.